# Создание подключения к Jira и выборка списка проектов

Tags: c#, jira

Здравствуйте. Есть установленная Jira, версии 5.2.11. На проект в c# установлен пакет Atlassian.sdk Версии 9.7.0 В коде пытаюсь создать коннект к Jira. Но есть проблемы. Вот как я делаю коннект:

```
Jira jiraConn = Jira.CreateRestClient("адрес джиры", "логин", "пароль");
```

Адрес к которому я конекчусь рабочий. Если я на него щёлкну, в visual studio он откроется на странице авторизации, вроде всё правильно. Но если я загляну в коннект, там везде пусто и нет проектов. Хотя реально они есть. И вот собственно мой запрос, что пока что не так важно, для начала хотелось бы что бы коннект правильно отработал.

```
string jqlString = "project = PRJ AND status = Closed AND resolved >= 2017-03-01 AND resolved <= 2017-10-26";
```

Comment: Так уберите фильтр из запроса и проверяйте. HTTP траффик смотрели? Запросы к джире уходят?

Comment: @tym32167 дело не в запросе, я после создания подключения, смотрю в отладчике в jiraConn, там пусто везде.

Comment: а http запросы проверяли? Поглядите фиддлером что от вашего клиента на сервер уходит и какие ответы приходят

Comment: @tym32167 можно поподробней. Что такое фиддлер? Как им пользоваться. И как посмотреть с помощью него то что вы сказали?

Comment: [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) - это инструмент, который позволяет подглядывать http трафик между вашим приложением  и внешним миров (и многое другое). Таких инструментов несколько, но мне нравится этот и он бесплатный. Если вы пишете приложение, которое работает с сервером по http протоколу, то знание какие именно http запросы ваше приложение отправляет и какие ответы получает, сэкономит кучу времени и нервов. Как им пользоваться написано на сайте, куда смотрит ссылка.